# building scala from source

Tags: scala, build, compilation, sbt

I'm trying to figure out how to build scala from a source code archive.  I see a build.sbt file but if I don't have scala installed, so how to do build scala?

I also see a Gemfile, implying that there are Ruby bindings. I checked the README.md but there isn't any information there sadly.

I don't know what to do to start building.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're talking about Scala 2 https://github.com/scala/scala and not Scala 3 https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty since you mentioned Gemfile (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/Gemfile).

The Gemfile is for Travis CI. So you can ignore it.

If you can see `build.sbt` then in order to build a project you need JVM and [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) installed, not Scala

https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html

> I checked the README.md but there isn't any information there sadly.

Actually, there is all necessary information in README:

https://github.com/scala/scala#using-the-sbt-build

> - `sbt dist/mkBin` generates runner scripts (`scala`, `scalac`, etc) in `build/quick/bin`
> - `sbt dist/mkPack` creates a build in the Scala distribution format in `build/pack`

Comment: should this be moved to: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/ because this is a question regarding How to Code a Minecraft 1.8 Hacked Client. As I'm having trouble with building mcp 9.10 which requires Scala 2.x

Comment: @WhitequillRiclo Can't see anything about Minecraft in your question

Comment: There isn't anything about Minecraft in my question. I was uncomfortable about asking about making a hacked client. Should I rephrase and move the question?

Comment: I'll just close this and re-post where with more detail into what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this tool (https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/) will let you easily download a working scala compiler & associated tools.  they, in turn, will make it possible to build a compiler from the source tree.  i'm assuming you've cloned https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty (scala 3)?

Comment: Most probably, Scala 2 https://github.com/scala/scala since OP mentions Gemfile (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/Gemfile)